# Enviar valor de um <a> onclick

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando pegar o valor de um `<a>` que mande para uma função em JavaScript, porém não sei o que está dando errado.

```
//HTML
<div id="dicaDiv" class="text-center">
    <p id="pDica1" style="display: inline;">Dica 1: <span id="mostrarDica1"><a value="dica1" href="javascript:gerarDica(this.value);">mostrar dica</a></span>.</p><br>
    <p id="pDica2" style="display: inline;">Dica 2: <span id="MostrarDica2"><a value="dica2" href="javascript:gerarDica(this.value);">mostrar dica</a></span>.</p><br>
</div>

//JS
var dica;
function gerarDica(dica) {
if(dica == "dica1") {
    if(randomClasse == 0)
        dica = "veículo";
    else if(randomClasse == 1)
        dica = "animal";
    else if(randomClasse == 2)
        dica = "cor";
    document.getElementById("mostrarDica1").innerHTML = dica;
    document.getElementById("botaoDica").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

A variável `randomClasse` está funcionando, o problema é quando eu tento colocar nesse `if(dica == "dica1")`.

Answer (score 0):

Sua pergunta ta meio confusa mas acho que é isso que voce quer

```
    //HTML
<div id="dicaDiv" class="text-center">
    <p id="pDica1" style="display: inline;">Dica 1: 
        <span id="mostrarDica1">
            <a href="#" onclick="gerarDica('dica1');">mostrar dica</a>
        </span>.
    </p>
    <br>
    <p id="pDica2" style="display: inline;">Dica 2: 
        <span id="MostrarDica2">
            <a href="#" onclick="gerarDica('dica2');">mostrar dica</a>
        </span>.
    </p>
    <br>
</div>

//JS
var dica;
function gerarDica(dica) {
    if(dica == "dica1") {
        if(randomClasse == 0)
            dica = "veículo";
        else if(randomClasse == 1)
            dica = "animal";
        else if(randomClasse == 2)
            dica = "cor";
        document.getElementById("mostrarDica1").innerHTML = dica;
        document.getElementById("botaoDica").style.display = "none";
    }
  }
```

Sugiro usar switch quando tiver mais de dois ifs encadeados

```
function gerarDica(dica) {
    if(dica == "dica1") {
        switch (randomClasse) {
          case 0:
            dica = "veículo";
            break;

          case 1:
            dica = "animal";
            break;

          case 2:
            dica = "cor";
            break;

          default:
            dica ='alguma valor padrao';
            break;
      }
        document.getElementById("mostrarDica1").innerHTML = dica;
        document.getElementById("botaoDica").style.display = "none";
    }
  }
```

Comment: continua não indo, https://jsfiddle.net/7y5ksugj/

Comment: Eu testei aqui e foi http://ws.ri2b.com.br/validcad.com.br/testes/teste.php

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer que um JavaScript seja executado ao clicar em um link, não use `href`, e sim `onclick`.

Outros detalhes:

- a tag `a` não tem atributo `value`. Então uma alternativa é passar o valor diretamente para a função `gerarDica`
- é costume deixar o `href` com `#` e fazer a função chamada no `onclick` retornar `false`, [para que o link não seja seguido](https://stackoverflow.com/a/128966).

Dei uma simplificada no seu código para que tenha somente as partes relevantes à solução deste problema específico, mas você pode adaptar para o seu código facilmente:

```js
function gerarDica(dica) {
    // vou só imprimir o valor para mostrar que está funcionando
    console.log(dica);

    // ... faz tudo que precisa fazer com a dica
  
    // retorna false para o link não ser "seguido"
    return false;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:return gerarDica('dica1');">mostrar dica1</a>
<br>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:return gerarDica('dica2');">mostrar dica2</a>
```

Comment: continua não indo https://jsfiddle.net/7y5ksugj/

Comment: "não indo" é muito vago, o que exatamente está ocorrendo? Bem, vi que você mudou o gerarDica, mas está usando aspas duplas dentro de aspas duplas, o que gera erro. Use aspas simples, como eu fiz acima (`gerarDica('dica2')` ao invés de `gerarDica("dica2")`). Não esqueça do `return gerarDica('dica2')` para evitar que os links sejam seguidos (o browser "recarrega a página" se não tiver o return). E os seus links "Tutorial" e "Jogar" também estão usando `href` ao invés de `onclick`

Comment: E depois do seu `if(dica == "dica1")` faltou abrir as chaves (`{`). E não existe nenhum elemento com `id` igual a `botaoDica`, por isso o `document.getElementById("botaoDica")` não acha nada, e ao tentar setar o `style` dele, dá erro.